# click on listView subItem

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to click on row in list view but my code only works when i pressed between two rows

you can see this : 
http://www.screencast.com/t/2vei8yOQh

note in rep.xml i using table layout and inside it rowTable
i uses this code :

```
  public class LastDaysActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_last_days);
    final Button newFourm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    LastDaysAdapter adapter = new LastDaysAdapter(this, getDates(),
            getApplicationContext(), getBusID());

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    newFourm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LastDaysActivity.this,
                    TabHostActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    TextView myView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String text = myView.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, text + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

edit xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow05"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/trans01" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="رقم اللوحة" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:text="التاريخ"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your .xml for your layout (the list items)

Comment: I suspect what's causing the trouble is the background (android:background="@drawable/trans01"). Try removing that and see if the code works as expected. If it is transparent, it may mess up with hit testing of the click event.

Comment: Please try to get data base on list item click position rather than clicked item view getText() I think you have custom adapter and you pass list this adapter to set your data so get data from this list based on item click postition which you getting in OnListItemClick() methid as params.

Comment: try setting the focusable to false, and also focusableInTouchmode to false to the textviews and table row in the xml, also set clickable to false.